# Calculating Pi with C

Tags: c

I want to calculate pi but I am getting 3.058403 as a result. How can I fix this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
double x = 0;
float g =0;

printf("How many terms to calculate pi to? ");
scanf("%f", &g);

int n;
for (n = 0; n < g ; n++){
  
     double z = 1.0 / (2 * n + 1);
     if ((n % 2) == 1){
        z = z * -1;
     }
     x = (x + z);
     }
     double p = 4 * x;
    printf("The value of pi is: %f", p);
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `g` is a double, and yet `%lu` is for unsigned longs..

Comment: The correct [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format specifier for `double` is `%lf`, however changing `g` to `float`, as you have done, is also a valid solution.

Comment: OT: don't use floating point variables for comparing integers.

Comment: Your code as it stands here works fine, but the number of terms must be big. What is your input?

Comment: my input is 12.

Comment: @Agah 12 is a very few terms, it's normal that you get the result you get. Try with 2000 terms or more.

Comment: When I enter `100000` terms, I get `3.141583` as a result, which is very accurate. Therefore, the algorithm seems to work. Higher number of terms give me even higher accuracy.

Comment: can i make this more accurate for every number ?

Comment: By using a better [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Pi_algorithms) that converges more quickly. Other SO [questions](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=algorithms+to+calculate+pi+quickly+site:stackoverflow.com) ask about *pi* too.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer because the actual answer has been discussed in the comment section.

Corrected version of your code:

- removed pointless parentheses
- use meaningful variable names
- use of `int` for integer comparison
- declaration of variables as close as possible to their scope
- code formatted properly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("How many terms to calculate pi to? ");

  int nbofterms;
  scanf("%d", &nbofterms);

  double x = 0;

  for (int n = 0; n < nbofterms; n++) {
    double z = 1.0 / (2 * n + 1);
    if (n % 2 == 1) {
      z *= -1;
    }
    x = (x + z);
  }

  double pi = 4 * x;
  printf("The value of pi is: %f", pi);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another correction: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)